# Do MV* architectural patterns apply not only to OO languages but also functional languages?

Tags: mvc, functional-programming, architectural-patterns, mvvm, mvp

I am learning about MV* architectural patterns, thanks to the help from several answers here. I learned that they are used for designing the architectures of user interactive applications.

I also learned a little about functional programming (Haskel, Scheme/Clojure, SML/OCaml, Scala).

I was wondering if MV* architecture patterns applies not only to OO languages but also functional languages? If not, what architectural patterns for designing interactive applications written in functional languages?

Does the answer depend on whether the applications written in functional languages run on server side or client side?

Are functional languages used only for writing server side applications not client side applications?

Functional languages often have more elegant design patterns (for components, at lower level than architectural patterns) than OO languages do. So I was wondering whether it is also the case for architectural patterns such as MV*.

Thanks.

Comment: MV* is not a programming language paradigm; it is a software pattern.  The two concepts are orthogonal to each other.